# ValueError: figure size must be positive finite not [1. 0.]

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I get the following wrror when i try to run this code , any ideas about what could have caused this ?

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

from kivy.app import App

import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dfguik import DfguiWidget


def create_dummy_data(size):


    user_ids = np.random.randint(1, 10000, 10)
    product_ids = np.random.randint(1, 10000, 100)

    def choice(*values):
        return np.random.choice(values, size)

    random_dates = [
        datetime.date(2016, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=int(delta))
        for delta in np.random.randint(1, 50, size)
    ]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        "Date": random_dates,
        "UserID": choice(*user_ids),
        "ProductID": choice(*product_ids),
        "IntColumn": choice(1, 2, 3),
        "FloatColumn": choice(np.nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0),
        "StringColumn": choice("A", "B", "C"),
        "Gaussian 1": np.random.normal(0, 1, size),
        "Gaussian 2": np.random.normal(0, 1, size),
        "Uniform": np.random.uniform(0, 1, size),
        "Binomial": np.random.binomial(20, 0.1, size),
        "Poisson": np.random.poisson(1.0, size),
    })

class DataFrameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        df = create_dummy_data(1000)
        return DfguiWidget(df)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DataFrameApp().run()
```

Comment: Where is this coming from `from dfguik import DfguiWidget`?

Comment: it's coming from here:https://github.com/MichaelStott/PandasDataframeGUIKivy/blob/master/dfguik.py

Comment: WARNING: trying this code made my graphic driver to crash. Watch out.